# How to undo strsplit to put multiple characters into one

Tags: r, undo, strsplit

Let's say I have a string of words

```
txt = "The licenses for most software"
length(txt)
1
```

I can use strsplit to split it into its composite words

```
t = unlist(strsplit(txt, split=" "))
length(t)
5
```

Now I want to undo what I did. How can I reconnect 5 words together into the original string?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
paste(t,collapse=" ") 
# [1] "The licenses for most software"
```